# Please help me understand this JavaScript code from "Ajax in Action"

Tags: javascript, ajax, this

I saw this code in Ajax in Action book and there are two things I'm not able to understand (Keep in mind I just started web programming and I'm still trying to understand how JavaScript works).

1. On line 37 or in function loadXMLDoc, why did the author declared a local variable "var loader=this;" and then used it in the call "net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(loader);" instead of just using "net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(this);"
2. Why did the author used "net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(loader);", instead of "this.onReadyState();"

```
    /*
    url-loading object and a request queue built on top of it
    */

    /* namespacing object */
    var net=new Object();

    net.READY_STATE_UNINITIALIZED=0;
    net.READY_STATE_LOADING=1;
    net.READY_STATE_LOADED=2;
    net.READY_STATE_INTERACTIVE=3;
    net.READY_STATE_COMPLETE=4;


    /*--- content loader object for cross-browser requests ---*/
    net.ContentLoader=function(url,onload,onerror,method,params,contentType){
      this.req=null;
      this.onload=onload;
      this.onerror=(onerror) ? onerror : this.defaultError;
      this.loadXMLDoc(url,method,params,contentType);
    }

    net.ContentLoader.prototype.loadXMLDoc=function(url,method,params,contentType){
      if (!method){
        method="GET";
      }
      if (!contentType && method=="POST"){
        contentType='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        this.req=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        this.req=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      if (this.req){
        try{
          var loader=this;
          this.req.onreadystatechange=function(){
            net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(loader);
          }
          this.req.open(method,url,true);
          if (contentType){
            this.req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
          }
          this.req.send(params);
        }catch (err){
          this.onerror.call(this);
        }
      }
    }


    net.ContentLoader.onReadyState=function(){
      var req=this.req;
      var ready=req.readyState;
      var httpStatus=req.status;
      if (ready==net.READY_STATE_COMPLETE){
        if (httpStatus==200 || httpStatus==0){
          this.onload.call(this);
        }else{
          this.onerror.call(this);
        }
      }
    }

    net.ContentLoader.prototype.defaultError=function(){
      alert("error fetching data!"
        +"\n\nreadyState:"+this.req.readyState
        +"\nstatus: "+this.req.status
        +"\nheaders: "+this.req.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>A `try/catch` statement in *ECMA-/Javascript* creates a new *Context*. Technically, this is similar to an `eval` statement and therefore an `eval Context`.</strike>

The current *Scope chain* is extended by that newly created "*eval Context*" and therefore, the *Context variable* `this`, would point to a wrong context when just invoked by `this.onReadyState();`.

By calling `net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(loader);` the author explicitly calls the method `onReadyState` with the context of the `loaded` object (and that is what `this` within the **callee** is referencing then). A **callee** is a function (-context...) with was called by a **caller** (-context).

---

> Long story short, ECMAscripts
>   `.call()` and `.apply()` methods allow
>   you to set a specific Context for a
>   function when invoked. This is
>   necessary here, because `try/catch`
>   creates a new Context and the value of
>   `this` within the called method would
>   be wrong.

---

While the above statement is true, it's not responsible here. It's not the Context from `try / catch` which is the problem , it's furthermore the Context by the created anonymous function

```
this.req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(loader);
}
```

Using `this` within that anonymous method would "again" reference a different Context. That is why the author cached the value from `this` in `loader` and invokes the method with that cached Context.

Comment: But here in the call "net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(loader);" loader is same as this within the try/catch block, i.e. it is still pointing to the context extended after try block. For what you are saying shouldn't he move the creation of the loader variable before the try block?

Comment: @NikhilRathod: I updated the answer. The author actually should move the storing of the `this value` before the `try/catch` indeed. It still works here, because the scope-chain lookup will resolve the method anyway.

Comment: @jAndy: So why did he create a anonymous function. what is wrong in "this.req.onreadystatechange=net.ContentLoader.onReadyState.call(this);"

Comment: @NikhilRathod: well, he assigns a function to the `onreadystatechange`-handler. That function is called each time the *XHR readystate* changes. The "problem" is that a new function, creates a new *Execution Context*. But the author wants to access/call the `onReadyState` method with a context from the parent context.

Comment: @NikhilRathod: Your example snippet, would assign the `result` from the execution of `onReadyState` to `onreadystatechange`, not a function.

Comment: @jAndy: I tried to delete my last comment as I understood what I was saying was wrong, but I was caught up with something. Anyways thanks for your help.